Struggling to get this scrollable table with fixed top and left side working
So I have this project where I have a page with a header and then a table.
Now for the table I need to have the top most row to be fixed AND also have the left most column be fixed when I scroll. I was able to get the vertical scrolling (with fixed top row) working but not the horizontal scroll bar (though the left most column is fixed so kind of working).
I have some code here for what I have so far: https://playcode.io/1945145
But my issue is this:

There is no horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the window. It should always be visible at the bottom of the window and not the bottom of page
The last row is cut off (i presume thats where the horizontal scroll bar is but i want the scroll bar to be bottom of window always visible)

Its built with React and Tailwind.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Many thanks in advance.

The bottom of the table extends outside the bottom of the top-level <div> element with the overflow-hidden class. You could consider adjusting the height applied to the <table> wrapper <div> so that it is the space left behind by the previous element:


function App() {
  const data = {
    columns: [
      'Column 1',
      'Column 2',
      'Column 3',
      'Column 4',
      'Column 5',
      'Column 6',
      'Column 7',
      'Column 8',
      'Column 9',
    ],
    rows: [
      ['Row 1', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 2', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 3', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 4', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 5', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 6', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 7', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 8', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 9', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 10', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 11', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 12', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 13', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 14', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 15', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 16', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 17', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 18', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 19', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 20', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 21', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 22', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 23', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 24', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 25', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 26', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 27', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 28', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 29', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 30', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      // Add more rows as needed
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-screen overflow-hidden">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between bg-white">
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-10 py-10">
          <div>LOGO Header</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="h-[calc(100vh-(theme(padding.10)*2)-theme(fontSize.base.1.lineHeight))] overflow-auto">
        <table className="min-w-full table-fixed border-collapse">
          <thead className="sticky top-0 z-20 bg-white">
            <tr>
              <th className="sticky left-0 z-30 border border-gray-200 bg-white p-2">Header</th>
              {data.columns.map((col, index) => (
                <th key={index} className="border border-gray-200 p-2">
                  {col}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
              <tr key={rowIndex}>
                <td className="sticky left-0 z-10 border border-gray-200 bg-white p-2">{row[0]}</td>
                {row.slice(1).map((cell, cellIndex) => (
                  <td key={cellIndex} className="min-w-96 border bg-white border-gray-200 p-2">
                    {cell}
                  </td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);

window.tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'my-indigo': '#4f45e5',
      },
    },
  },
};
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



You could also use a vertical flex layout to have the browser do the mathematics for you:


function App() {
  const data = {
    columns: [
      'Column 1',
      'Column 2',
      'Column 3',
      'Column 4',
      'Column 5',
      'Column 6',
      'Column 7',
      'Column 8',
      'Column 9',
    ],
    rows: [
      ['Row 1', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 2', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 3', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 4', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 5', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 6', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 7', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 8', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 9', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 10', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 11', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 12', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 13', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 14', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 15', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 16', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 17', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 18', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 19', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 20', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 21', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 22', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 23', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 24', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 25', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 26', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 27', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 28', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 29', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      ['Row 30', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 6', 'Data 7'],
      // Add more rows as needed
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-stretch h-screen overflow-hidden">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between bg-white">
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-10 py-10">
          <div>LOGO Header</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="min-h-0 flex-1 overflow-auto">
        <table className="min-w-full table-fixed border-collapse">
          <thead className="sticky top-0 z-20 bg-white">
            <tr>
              <th className="sticky left-0 z-30 border border-gray-200 bg-white p-2">Header</th>
              {data.columns.map((col, index) => (
                <th key={index} className="border border-gray-200 p-2">
                  {col}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
              <tr key={rowIndex}>
                <td className="sticky left-0 z-10 border border-gray-200 bg-white p-2">{row[0]}</td>
                {row.slice(1).map((cell, cellIndex) => (
                  <td key={cellIndex} className="min-w-96 border bg-white border-gray-200 p-2">
                    {cell}
                  </td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);

window.tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'my-indigo': '#4f45e5',
      },
    },
  },
};
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>




Ah thats beautiful, makes sense! thanks, been stuck on this for ages!
